# Sum pageviews over array

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to solve a problem for a couple of days already, but I'm completely stuck:

- I do have a basic pageviews table from Snowplow Analytics. I'm creating a session table from that. This table has arrays to structure my data.
- Now when I do a sum(count_page_views) the totals are right.
- As soon as I add a date dimension date(session_start), the sum for this day is completely wrong.

**This is what the table should look like. (Count distinct on pageview id)**

[image: Right data]

**This is what it looks like with my session table SQL:**
[image: Wrong data]

I'm pretty certain I misunderstand something about the way summing arrays and array_length work, but I have no idea, what is wrong...

**SQL for session table**

```
with all_page_views as (
  select
    *
  from
    `page_views_table`

),
sessions_agg as (
  select
    pv.session_id,
    array_agg(
      pv
      order by
        pv.page_view_in_session_index
    ) as all_pageviews
  from
    all_page_views as pv
  group by
    1
),
sessions_agg_xf as (
  select
    session_id,
    all_pageviews,
    (
      select
        struct(
          min(page_view_start) as session_start,
          max(page_view_end) as session_end
        )
      from
        unnest(all_pageviews)
    ) as timing
  from
    sessions_agg
),
sessions as (
  select
    timing.session_start,
    timing.session_end,
    array_length(all_pageviews) as count_page_views
  from
    sessions_agg_xf
)
select
  sum(count_page_views )
from
  sessions

  where date(session_start) = "2020-02-01"
```

Comment: You said "as soon as I add a date dimension date(session_start)" the query starts giving strange numbers. But if you had no "session_start", how would this query work? I see no date filtering, nor grouping anywhere else.

Comment: Basically it gives me a session table with all separate page views per session as an array.

Comment: Basically it gives me a session table with all page views per session as arrays attached to each session. count_page_views is then the count of page_views for each session. To generate the session table, the last select is just a star select. I'm trying to use the result in datastudio, with session_start as date and sum(count_page_views) as metric but this is somehow skewed. The first session_start dates in the row have to many aggregated page_views, the last dates in the row don't have enough. The total is still the same as it is in the base page_views_table.

Comment: I believe I've found the problem somewhere else. There was a bug in Snowplow that didn't reset the session id, so my sessionization is wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I've found the problem somewhere else. There was a bug in Snowplow that didn't reset the session id, so my sessionization is wrong...

https://github.com/snowplow/snowplow-javascript-tracker/issues/718